# localization problem in iPhone App with XCode

Tags: iphone, localization

i need to localize an existing iphone app. I've added strings files for German and English, which work well.

BUT !

I've also opened the Info-Pane of the XIB Files, klicked "add Localization", chose the languages  (German and Englisch).  In the View of all Ressources in XCode is see under the XIB Files now "German" and "Englisch".

I can translate all design elements in Interface Builder for German and Englisch. If i start the App on the Device or in Simulator there is always the german language displayed, also if i change the device language to "English". I also cleared all targets and deleted the app on the device and the simulator before testing.

What am i doing wrong ??

Any help is much apprechiated !

Greetings

MadMaxApp

Comment: open your compiled app as a folder and look for your english localization files there.

Comment: There have been only German.lproj and Englisch.lproj. The folders need to be named en.lproj and de.lproj. I don't know why XCode creates the wrong folders. If you use "Add localization" for a XIB File, XCode uses the Full Name of a language instead of the short name. Manually setting the localization to "de" and "en" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok ... looks like XCode has still a bug. The localization should not be named "German" and "Englisch". You need to name it "de" and "en". After clearning all targets and running in Simulator the right language xib is displayed.